# bash index multiple different arrays at same index for loop

Tags: arrays, bash, list, indexing

Let's say I have three arrays that look like the following:

```
a=(banana apple grape)
b=(1 2 3)
c=(yellow red purple)
```

If I wanted to loop through such that each index of each variable is matched, how would I do this? For example, I would want something like the following:

```
for i in range(0,len(a))
do
    echo "$a[i] $b[i] $c[i]"
done
```

such that the results would be:

```
banana 1 yellow
apple 2 red
grape 3 purple
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax to access array elements is `${array[index]}`.

```sh
for ((i=0 ; i < ${#a[@]} ; ++i)) ; do
    echo "${a[i]} ${b[i]} ${c[i]}"
done
```

You can use `seq` to simulate Python's `range`:

```sh
for i in $(seq 1 ${#a[@]}) ; do 
    echo "${a[i-1]} ${b[i-1]} ${c[i-1]}"
done
```

where `${#array[@]}` returns the size of the array.

Comment: ...while one _can_ use `seq`, I'm not sure there's any compelling respect in which it can be argued to be better than the C-style for syntax used above it.

Comment: The fact that you need length-1 was solved in Python by not including the last element in the loop, or in Perl by the distinction between `scalar @array` and `$#array`. In bash, you can use `seq 0 $((${#a[@]}-1))`, but it becomes really hard to read :-)